# Best python data stucture linking images together

Tags: python

Me and my girlfriend are planning to code a video game during this summer using **pygame**.
In the video game, we would need to link real images we took and link them to one another.
For example, the first image is of the entrance of the house, we would need to link 3 photos to it (right, left, forward). after the player inserted one of those requests, he would get to a new image that will also be linked to 3 more directions. and so forth.
What is the best data structure we can use to link those images? Where can I learn how to use it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper data structure the achieve what you want, however you can really easily make one:

```py
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, front, back, left, right):
        self.front = back
        self.back = bottom
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

So that you can link Tiles (or Maps, or Rooms, or whatever) one to the others, and access the one you'd like from the one you are at.
I guess you can see that as a four-ways linked list, but I don't like the `list` naming so much as there is no ordering.